# How to fix blurry svg icons in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, icons

Our small (16px), circular icons suddenly degraded in quality on chrome with no change to our code or assets. The svgs look fine on a macbook screen, but blur on a monitor. Current running theory is a chrome update, but am looking for possible solutions/fixes. Any information or advice welcome.

[example of blurry edges on an icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlNQ6.png)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M50,0a50,50,0,1,0,50,50A50,50,0,0,0,50,0Zm0,91.6667A41.6667,41.6667,0,1,1,91.6667,50,41.6668,41.6668,0,0,1,50,91.6667Z"/>
  <g>
    <circle cx="49.2659" cy="75.9917" r="5.7828" fill="#6d6e71"/>
    <path d="M53.7632,63.0029H43.85c0-10.0845,5.03-15.1208,9.0712-19.1674,3.326-3.33,5.5236-5.5311,5.5236-10.2049,0-6.4239-6.9209-6.6089-7.71-6.6089-.3743,0-9.1787.0818-9.1787,7.16H31.642c0-11.2085,9.6047-17.0731,19.0922-17.0731,11.57,0,17.6239,8.3117,17.6239,16.5224,0,8.7764-4.6706,13.4524-8.4225,17.21C56.3524,54.4287,53.7632,57.0211,53.7632,63.0029Z" fill="#6d6e71"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you add some of the code to your question? The SVG, the HTML context and maybe CSS.

Comment: if this is a public site can you add a link?